# How to readonly setState to a specific type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

I am trying to setState from a specific component like this.

```
const [paramList, setParamList] = useState<Parameters<any>[] | undefined>();
```

the component type is like that

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

but when try to setParamlist it shows error as below.

```
    setParamList(renderState.parameters);
```

```
(parameter) renderState: RenderState
Argument of type 'ReadonlyMap<string, any> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<unknown[][] | undefined>'.
  Type 'ReadonlyMap<string, any>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<unknown[][] | undefined>'.
    Type 'ReadonlyMap<string, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'unknown[][]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this. It should be in Array.

```
const [paramList, setParamList] = useState<Array<Parameter>>();
```